# Pull info from Google maps api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working towards building a simple form that is sent off as an email and will be using on of Google's API's for the address field. I've read about using the autocomplete portion where the user starts to type an address and it recommends one. So if I start to type 12 West, it would recommend and allow me to choose 12 Westmount Drive, Cayley, n2n 5h8, Alberta, Canada.

I am wondering in the backend if its possible to split this info into street, city, postal code, province, and country. That way I can include the full address in the email and then also use street and city info in a separate paragraph.

Comment: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulling specific fields out of the address returned by Google is definitely possible.

Assuming that you are using [Places Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#address_forms), you will have access to a [PlaceResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceResult) object. The PlaceResult object will have a property called `address_components` that is an array of [GeocoderAddressComponent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderAddressComponent) objects.

Each GeocoderAddressComponent has a `types` array that contains the name of the component, or multiple names if there are multiple ways of describing it. An example `address_components` object can be found at [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#geocoding-request-and-response-latitudelongitude-lookup).

You could loop over all of the elements in the `address_components` array looking for the names `route` and `sublocality`, which would give you individual values for street and city respectively.

Answer (score 0):

/*I am assuming that you would like to send an email after they filled out your form is that correct?

I you would like to retain this form info gather the info into a database for future use. Then you can query info into send form.

Here is the code that may help you?*/

for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {

```
var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];

if (componentForm[addressType]) {
  var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
  document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;

  your_obj[addresType] = val;

}
```

}

//and after that you can use it where you uant like:
var postal_code = your_obj['postal_code'];

//check first console.log() to know all items in your_obj
console.log(your_obj);